# How to remove Edit and Delete button from mini-cart and cart page for specific product?

Tags: cart, mini-cart, delete, edit

I want to remove edit and delete button from mini-cart and cart page for specific product only. How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share on which criteria you want to hide edit/delete option for specific product? I mean conditions for specific product.

Comment: @DharaBhatti if i have multiple products in minicart/cart then i want to hide or remove edit/delete button for specific product only

Comment: You can use jquery like : if added 4 or more products then `.minicart-items .product.actions{display:none;}`

Comment: @DharaBhatti If "ABC" product in minicart/cart then i want to remove or hide edit/delete button from "ABC" product only.

Answer (score 0):

To simply remove the edit/delete links in mini-cart you can extend the below file on your theme or in module and remove the ***product actions***  div class

```
Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

But to remove based condition you have to create plugin for the class

```
\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem::doGetItemData
```

The above file is method doGetItemData() passes the arguments for the buttons display

So our plugin di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem">
        <plugin name="Yourmodule_Checkout::add-custom-attribute-to-cart-minicart"
                type="Yourmodule\Checkout\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItemPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and the plugin file DefaultItemPlugin.php

```
  <?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Yourmodule\Checkout\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData;
    
    class DefaultItemPlugin
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $productRepository;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
        ) {
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        }
    
        public function afterGetItemData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem $subject, $result)
        {
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($result['product_sku']);
    
            return \array_merge(
                ['our_custom_attribute' => $this->showlinks()], 
                $result
            );
        }
       protected function canDisplayActionLinks()
           {
             if (condition check) {
              return false;
           } else {
            return true;
           }
       }
  }
```

Now in our default.html file under "product actions"  div class check for our_custom_attribute value and display links accordingly

```
<div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: showlinks -->
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
```